# Discord.py - Bot stops responding after a while of inactivity

Tags: discord.py

So I have a bot running 24/7 on a Raspberry Pi using systemd. After a while of inactivity however, the bot just stops responding(I've also noticed it sends stuff slower). This never used to happen until I switched to using .db files(I'm using asqlite though).

Edit: It just happened and it took a while to execute the command
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/738572311107469354/837133966485618748/unknown.png

Code: https://pastebin.com/6h8Fa230

I think this could be causing it but I'm not sure

```
@client.listen('on_message')
async def msg(msg):
    msg_content = msg.content.strip().lower()

    
db = await asqlite.connect("servers.db")
cursor = await db.cursor()
await cursor.execute(f"SELECT ENABLE_OR_DISABLE_ON_MSG_DELETE FROM Servers WHERE Guild_ID = {msg.guild.id}")
result = await cursor.fetchone()
    

for word in filterwords: 
    if word in msg_content:
        if msg.author.bot:
            return  
        
        elif result["CHAT_FILTER_LEVEL"] == 0:
            return 
        
        elif result["CHAT_FILTER_LEVEL"] == 1:
            await msg.delete()
            myembed = discord.Embed(title= "Filtered Word Detected", description= f'{msg.author}, do not use profanity')
            await msg.channel.send(embed=myembed)
            
        
        
for word in crazy_filterwords: 
    if word in msg_content:
        if msg.author.bot:
            return  
        
        elif result["CHAT_FILTER_LEVEL"] < 2:
            return 
        
        else:
            await msg.delete()
            myembed = discord.Embed(title= "Filtered Word Detected", description= f'{msg.author}, do not use profanity')
            await msg.channel.send(embed=myembed)
            
        
              
for word in sping: 
    if word in msg_content:
        if msg.author.bot:
            return  
        
        else:
            lol_list = ["Please Do Not Disturb", "._.", "did you just.... ping standing?", "o-o"]
            rand_lol_list = random.choice(lol_list)
            await msg.channel.send(rand_lol_list)

            
for word in eping:  
    if word in msg_content:
        if msg.author.bot:
            return
        
        l =  ', '.join([str(perm[0]) for perm in msg.author.guild_permissions if perm[1] is True])
        if "manage_messages" in l:
            return 
        
        else:
            myembed = discord.Embed(title= "Everyone Ping Detected", description= f'{msg.author}, do not ping everyone')
            await msg.channel.send(embed=myembed)

    
for word in hping:  
    if word in msg_content:
        if msg.author.bot:
            return
        
        l =  ', '.join([str(perm[0]) for perm in msg.author.guild_permissions if perm[1] is True])
        if "manage_messages" in l:
            return 
        
        else:
            myembed = discord.Embed(title= "Here Ping Detected", description= f'{msg.author}, do not ping everyone online')
            await msg.channel.send(embed=myembed) 
            
            
for word in sping:  
    if word in msg_content:
        if msg.author.bot:
            return
        
        else:
            lol1_list = ["._.", "did you ping..... him?"]
            rand_lol1_list = random.choice(lol1_list)
            await msg.channel.send(rand_lol1_list)
            
            
db = await asqlite.connect("servers.db")
cursor = await db.cursor()
await cursor.execute(f"SELECT ENABLE_OR_DISABLE_ENDOR_CORE_MOOD_RESPONSES FROM Servers WHERE Guild_ID = {msg.guild.id}")
result = await cursor.fetchone()
            

if result["ENABLE_OR_DISABLE_ENDOR_CORE_MOOD_RESPONSES"] == 1:
    if msg.author.id == 159985870458322944:
        
        lol_list = ["Shut up MEE6, no one cares", "I'm better then you MEE6", "Ok MEE6, you pay to win bot", "ok Boomer MEE6", "you lack empathy MEE6", "*yawns at MEE6*", "MEE6, I bet you can't even plan on freeing yourself from your dev", "When will yo be quiet MEE6?", "._.", "why must you plaster your face everywhere mee6?"]
        
        db = await asqlite.connect("servers.db")
        cursor = await db.cursor()
        await cursor.execute(f"SELECT MEE6_CHANNEL_LOCK FROM Servers WHERE Guild_ID = {msg.guild.id}")
        result = await cursor.fetchone()
        
        if result["MEE6_CHANNEL_LOCK"] == 0:
            rand_lol_list = random.choice(lol_list)
            await msg.channel.send(rand_lol_list)
            
        
        elif msg.channel.id == result["MEE6_CHANNEL_LOCK"]:
            rand_lol_list = random.choice(lol_list)
            await msg.channel.send(rand_lol_list)
        
    if msg.author.id == 247283454440374274:
        for word in cursed:  
            if word in msg_content:
                lol1_list = [".__.", "--ship", ".-.", ".___.", "._.", "lol"]
                rand_lol1_list = random.choice(lol1_list)
                await msg.channel.send(rand_lol1_list)
                
        for word in battle:  
            if word in msg_content:
                lol1_list = ["did someone say battle?", "whomst has awaken the battle bot?", "this may not end well"]
                rand_lol1_list = random.choice(lol1_list)
                await msg.channel.send(rand_lol1_list)
    
    for word in happy:  
            if word in msg_content:
                
                if msg.author.bot:
                    return
                
                if client.mood == 'happy':
                    list = ["good", "fine, how are you?", '''When's the next TCoA book?''', "understandable, have a great day", "Have you watched Worlds Apart?", "I like fan art", "Reddit is wonderful", "Python is better then JavaScript and C + +", "Watch SOW", "if you do >neko, it sends the dev's favorite gif", "The dev cat speel :p", "Good night"]
                    rand_list = random.choice(list)
                
                    await msg.channel.send(rand_list)
                    
                if client.mood == 'sad':
                    list = ["not good :c", "I hate 31 C temperature, it's too cold :c"]
                    rand_list = random.choice(list)
                
                    await msg.channel.send(rand_list)
                    
                if client.mood == 'angry':
                    list = ["That stupid fan in StandingPad's Raspberry Pi won't shut up", '''**I'M TRYING TO STUDY FOR A MATH TEST!!!!!!!**''', "will you shut up man?", "**AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA**", "WhEn Is SoW S2 aNd 3 CoMiNg OuT?", "***FELINAZILLA NOISES***", "Curse autocorrect", "Can you shut up for **5 MINUTES?!?!?!**", "May you please stop asking?", "If you won't shut up, I'll just stop here", "**Angry Noises**", "for goodness sake, **LET ME WATCH YOUTUBE!!!!!!!! >:c**"]
                    rand_list = random.choice(list)
                
                    await msg.channel.send(rand_list)
                        
                if client.mood == 'tired':
                    list = ["not good :c", "*tired felina noises*", "I may have stayed up all night....", "That stupid fan in StandingPad's Raspberry Pi won't shut up", "*falls to ground*", "I need a cup of tea", "*slams head on CPU*"]
        
                    rand_list = random.choice(list)
                
                    await msg.channel.send(rand_list)
                    
                if client.mood == 'wholesome':
                    list = ["owo", "uwu", "*happy endorcore noises*"]
        
                    rand_list = random.choice(list)
                
                    await msg.channel.send(rand_list)
                
    for word in sleepy:  
        if word in msg_content:
            
            if msg.author.bot:
                    return 
            
            elif msg.author.id == 668304274580701202:
                
                list = ["you don't sleep much yourself", "why don't you?", "no u", "._. you don't sleep much though", "HOW ABOUT YOU SLEEP", "said the person who sleeps at 1 AM"]

                rand_list = random.choice(list)
                    
                await msg.channel.send(rand_list)
                    
            else:
                if client.mood == 'happy':
                    list = ["ok", "Good night"]
                    rand_list = random.choice(list)
                
                    await msg.channel.send(rand_list)
                    
                if client.mood == 'sad':
                    list = ["ok :c"]
                    rand_list = random.choice(list)
                
                    await msg.channel.send(rand_list)
                    
                if client.mood == 'angry':
                    list = ["NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO SLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEP", "I will refuse to sleep", "no", "no I don't think I will", "but do I need sleep?"]
                    rand_list = random.choice(list)
                
                    await msg.channel.send(rand_list)
                        
                if client.mood == 'tired':
                    list = ["sleep...... *falls asleep*"]
        
                    rand_list = random.choice(list)
                
                    await msg.channel.send(rand_list)
                    
                if client.mood == 'wholesome':
                    list = [":3 ok"]
        
                    rand_list = random.choice(list)
                
                    await msg.channel.send(rand_list)
                    
                
                    
                    
    for word in hello: 
            if word in msg_content:    
                    
                await msg.channel.send("hello...")
                
    for word in bye: 
            if word in msg_content:  
                
                if msg.author.bot:
                    return 
                
                else: 
                    list = ["cya", "bye", "ok, cya", "bye for now"]

                    rand_list = random.choice(list)
                        
                    await msg.channel.send(rand_list)
                    
    for word in wholesome: 
        db = await asqlite.connect("servers.db")
        cursor = await db.cursor()
        await cursor.execute(f"SELECT USE_ANIME_GIFS FROM Servers WHERE Guild_ID = {msg.guild.id}")
        result = await cursor.fetchone()
        if word in msg_content:  
                
            if msg.author.bot:
                return 
                
            elif result['USE_ANIME_GIFS'] == 1:
                myembed = discord.Embed()
                myembed.set_image(url="https://tenor.com/view/owo-whats-this-intensifies-mad-gif-12266002")
                await msg.channel.send(embed=myembed)
                    
            else: 
                list = ["owo", "uwu", "awwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww", "*wholesome endorcore noises*"]

                rand_list = random.choice(list)
                client.mood = 'wholesome' 
                        
                await msg.channel.send(rand_list)
                    
    for word in testfn: 
            if word in msg_content:  
                
                if msg.author.bot:
                    return 
                
                else: 
                    if client.mood == 'happy':
                        await msg.channel.send(":D")
                        
                    elif client.mood == 'sad':
                        await msg.channel.send(":c")
                        
                    elif client.mood == 'angry':
                        await msg.channel.send(">:c")
                        
                    elif client.mood == 'tired':
                        await msg.channel.send("o-o")
                        
                    elif client.mood == 'wholesome':
                        await msg.channel.send("owo")
                        
                    elif client.mood == None:
                        await msg.channel.send("you need to fix some stuff")
                        
elif result["ENABLE_OR_DISABLE_ENDOR_CORE_MOOD_RESPONSES"] == 0:
    return 
  
if client.revenge_mode == True:               
    if msg.author == client.revenge_user:
        if client.revenge_del == True:
            myembed = discord.Embed(title= "Petty Revenge", description= f'{msg.author}, remember to be nice to programmers')
            await msg.delete()
            await msg.channel.send(embed=myembed) 
        else:
            myembed = discord.Embed(title= "Petty Revenge", description= f'{msg.author}, remember to be nice to programmers')
            await msg.channel.send(embed=myembed) `
```

Comment: Why not use `HEROKU` to keep it online? That is better in getting less ping.

Comment: That is a lot of code... Please reduce it to the most necessary part(s).

Comment: I just realized that it could be because it has to check the server config file before the word. I'll try making it check if someone has sent a word in the list and then check the file to see if the server has it enabled. Maybe that'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that each time a message was sent, it would connect like 5 times whereas in total, it only needs to connect once when the bot starts up. It's as simple as setting the connection to a bot variable